# Discovery for bluetooth devices does not work

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to give to my app the feature of bond with new devices but my code does not work and i do not have any crash

```
        package com.kyuukun.boltcontroller.Command;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.UUID;

    public class DataControl
    {
        private BluetoothAdapter btadapter;
        private ArrayList paired = new ArrayList();;
        private BluetoothDevice connected;
        private BluetoothSocket socket;
        private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

        public DataControl(BluetoothAdapter adapter)
        {
            this.btadapter = adapter;
        }

        public BluetoothAdapter getAdapter()
        {
            return btadapter;
        }

        public ArrayList getPaired()
        {
            return paired;
        }

        public void startPaired(Activity act)
        {

            if(!btadapter.getBondedDevices().isEmpty())
            {
                for(BluetoothDevice d : btadapter.getBondedDevices())
                {
                    paired.add(d);
                }
            }

            btadapter.startDiscovery();

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

            BroadcastReceiver r = new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                    String action = intent.getAction();

                    Log.d("SENPAI", action);

                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
                    {
                        BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                        paired.add(device);

                    } else {}
                }
            };

            act.registerReceiver(r, filter);

            receiver = r;

        }


        public boolean startConnection(BluetoothDevice device)
        {
            boolean c = false;

            if(paired.contains(device))
            {

                BluetoothSocket sck;

                try {
                    sck = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.randomUUID());
                    sck.connect();
                    this.socket = sck;
                    this.connected = device;
                    c = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return c;
        }

        public BroadcastReceiver getReceiver()
        {
            return receiver;
        }

        public boolean send(String s)
        {

            boolean sd = false;

            if(connected != null && socket != null)
            {
                try {
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(s.getBytes());
                    sd = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    sd = false;
                }
            }

            return sd;
        }

        public String getData()
        {
            String s = "";

            if(connected != null && socket != null)
            {
                InputStream stream;

                try {
                    stream = socket.getInputStream();

                    if(stream.available() > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] b = new byte[stream.available() + 1];

                        stream.read(b);

                        String newstring = new String(b);

                        s.concat(newstring);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return s;
        }






        }
```

Code on activity:

```
    MainActivity.control.startPaired(LoadingActivity.this);

                                if(MainActivity.control.getPaired().size() > 0)
                                {
                                    MainActivity.control.getAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, PairedDevicesActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                    break;

                                }
```

What i receive on Log:

08-27 22:38:36.049 26687-26687/com.kyuukun.boltcontroller D/SENPAI: android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED

When i get the bonded divices it works fine but when i try to get new devices it does not do nothing.